# Bootstrap-select displays two selects menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Objective

To implement styling on the select tag using the [Bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) library.

### Problem

I am getting two selects rather than just one dropdown menu.

[image]

### Question

What do i need to change in my javascript or elsewhere to get it to display correctly

### Code

Demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/VvGEwP)

#### HTML

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-hidden="true">Choose one...</option>
    <option>BBQ Pork</option>
    <option>Bacon</option>
    <option>Sausage</option>
</select>
```

#### Script library order

- //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js

#### Javascript (I placed it in a script tag after the libraries)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); 
});
```

Comment: You havent added the CSS file for [Bootstrap-Select](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css)

Comment: @vanburen yes, i missed that. I am tempted to delete the question but since it might help someone later, I would like to leave it up. If you would like to add that as an answer I will accept it. Otherwise I will answer my own question with the input you gave. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks and glad I could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add the [Bootstrap-select](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css) CSS file.